# Fetch data from two tables Python

Tags: jquery, python, mysql, join

Hi i need to fetch data from two tables the Id of first in the foreign key for other

this is my code

```
def allplayers(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    player_list = myplayer.objects.all()
    get_player_vital=[]
    for i in player_list:
        get_player_vital = [vitals.objects.filter(playerID =i.id )]

    paginator = Paginator(player_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('allplayers.html', {"contacts": contacts,'get_player_vital':get_player_vital})
```

when i print get_player_vital in template it returns only last record

Answer (score 0):

You need to do smth like this, I guess:

```
def allplayers(request):
    player_list = myplayer.objects.all()
    get_player_vital = [vitals.objects.filter(playerID__in=player_list.values_list('id', flat=True))]
   ...
   return render_to_response('allplayers.html', {"contacts": contacts,'get_player_vital':get_player_vital})
```

because you create new `list` object every iteration loop, than consists of only one object.